# detect 4 interesting pixels

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, pixel

I read this picture using OpenCV:

[image]

I detect the boundaries of the objects inside it and display the picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


im=cv2.imread('db/4.jpg')
#mask=np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
imgray=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(imgray,242,245,235)
contours,hierarchy=cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow("GL",im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I want to do:

I want to have the coordinates of 4 pixels belonging to one of the contours and:

- First one is the closet from the X axis
- Second one is the farest from the X axis
- Third one is the closet from the Y axis
- Fourth one is the farest from the Y axis

Note that the number of contours variable in my code can vary depending on the picture I read.

Comment: Something like [boundingRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#boundingrect)?

Comment: @beaker No. You see the variable `contours` in my program ? all the green pixels (the contours of the objects) are saved there as a list of arrays. I want to look in that list of arrays for the 4 pixels I mentioned.

Comment: So you want the bounding box of all of the contours grouped together? Like a global min-X, global max-X?

Comment: The picture is just an example, it has nothing to do with geometrical shapes. And I want only to get those 4 pixels (the most bottom, top, left and right ones). @beaker

Comment: Draw it. I didn't reference any geometrical shapes and repeating that you want 4 points without adding any clarifying information won't get us anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stack all contours into one array `green` and search for the minimum/maximum x/y value:

```
green = np.vstack(contours).reshape((-1, 2))
print "Min X:", green[np.where(green[:, 0] == green[:, 0].min()), :]
print "Man X:", green[np.where(green[:, 0] == green[:, 0].max()), :]
print "Min Y:", green[np.where(green[:, 1] == green[:, 1].min()), :]
print "Man Y:", green[np.where(green[:, 1] == green[:, 1].max()), :]
```

Note that, especially for the rectangle, there are multiple pixels meeting your requirement, because they have equal distance from the x or y axis.

Here is a visualization of the "four" pixels:

[image]

The generating PyLab code:

```
pl.imshow(im)
pl.gca().autoscale(False)
minX = np.where(green[:, 0] == green[:, 0].min())
maxX = np.where(green[:, 0] == green[:, 0].max())
minY = np.where(green[:, 1] == green[:, 1].min())
maxY = np.where(green[:, 1] == green[:, 1].max())
pl.plot(green[minX, 0], green[minX, 1], 'ro')
pl.plot(green[maxX, 0], green[maxX, 1], 'go')
pl.plot(green[minY, 0], green[minY, 1], 'bo')
pl.plot(green[maxY, 0], green[maxY, 1], 'yo')
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly.  Thank you so much. Last question if I may:  What if I want to get only one pixel for the max Y because as you said the line of that rectangle has lot of pixels that satisfy the need ? You answered my question, I know i have not the right to ask this , but it sounds too easy for you.

Comment: @Kabyle: No worries. You can add `[0][0]` after the `where` commands to get the first indices only. So you always use one contour point only.